# Session_start se inicia pero no redirecciona a la página especificada

Tags: php, mysqli, api

```html
<?php
session_start(); // Iniciando sesion
$error=''; // Variable para almacenar el mensaje de error
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['nombre']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
else
{
// Define $username y $password
$username=$_POST['nombre'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$nivel=$_SESSION['nivel']    
// Estableciendo la conexion a la base de datos
include("api.php");//Contienen las variables, el servidor, usuario, contraseña y nombre  de la base de datos
include("inc/ajustes.php");//Contiene de conexion a la base de datos

// Para proteger de Inyecciones SQL 
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($username,ENT_QUOTES)));
$password =  sha1($password);//Algoritmo de encriptacion de la contraseña 

$sql= "SELECT * 
        FROM egg_usuarios nivel
        WHERE nombre_usuario='{$_REQUEST['nombre']}'
        AND password=SHA1('{$_REQUEST['password']}')
        ";
$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$numero=mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($counter==0){
    $error = "Usuario o la contraseña es inválida.";
  
 
} else {
 $_SESSION['login_user_sys']=$username;// Iniciando la sesion
  header("location: u_principal.php"); // Redireccionando a la pagina 
 
}
}
}
?>
```

### Session_start se ejecuta pero..

No consigo que se redireccione al 'u_principal.php'.
He comprobado que los datos se envían y se establece la sesión.
El formulario de login está en otro archivo php.
Es muy posible que tenga fallos, pero llevo tiempo intentando dar con el problema y no soy capaz de verlo.

Comment: No devuelve ningún error? Has comprobado que la query y la conexión se ejecutan correctamente (con `if($query){}else{/*error*/}`)?

Comment: Quizás debas agregas un slash antes del `u_principal.php`, así: `header('location: /u_principal.php');`

Comment: Si lo dá, no lo veo. Lo que he hecho para comprobarlo ha sido en la pagina del formulario poner: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['nombre']); ?> y cuando el usuario es correcto escribe su nombre...@Jose

Comment: Gracias @RimuruTempest, lo acabo de probar y tampoco...

Comment: Por sierto, te recomiendo que no uses `sha1` para encriptar las contraseñas ya que es poco seguro. Usa `$password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);` y `password_verify` para verificarla en cada inició de sesión.

Comment: También usa esa funcion para registrar las contraseñas en tu base de datos. Aquí los enlaces [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php) y [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: @RimuruTempest Gracias por tu aportación.

Comment: Una duda, el último if que tienes evalúa si $counter==0, ¿pero dónde tienes creada esa variable?

Comment: @unanobot, Gracias también por tu comentario. Lo cambie ya que tenías razón pero tampoco funcionó. De todos modos, he encontrado otra forma de hacerlo que compartiré ahora.

Answer (score 0):

Soy relativamente nueva en ésto de las sesiones, el código de mi pregunta de momento no he podido solucionarlo. Uno de los fallos, aunque tampoco funciona, podría ser la variable 'counter' que cambié por 'numero' pero sin resultado satisfactorio. Por otra parte, error mio al deducir que se iniciaba la sesión. No era así, lo que hacía era mostrar el nombre del usuario escrito en el input! Fallo gordo!
He solucionado el inicio de sesión de otra manera, quizá no sea la más correcta ni fina, ya que lo valido todo en la página del formulario del login. Pero de momento me sirve, éso sí, tengo pendiente el tema del password hash y password verify sugeridos por Rimuro.
Comparto el código por si puede ser útil a otra persona.

```html
<body>
<?php
 require('inc/ajustes.php');
 // Incluyo la base de datos.
 if (isset($_POST['nombre'])){
 // Quito las barras invertidas.
 $nombre = stripslashes($_REQUEST['nombre']);
 // Elimino los espacios en blanco.    
 $nombre = trim($_REQUEST['nombre']); 
 // Convierto caracteres especiales en entidades HTML    
 $nombre = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['nombre']);    
 // Escapo caracteres especiales en una cadena.
 $nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$nombre);
   
 $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
 $password = trim($_REQUEST['password']);
 $password = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['password']);
 $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);
 //Compruebo que el usuario existe en la base de datos.
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `egg_usuarios` WHERE nombre_usuario='$nombre'
 and password= SHA1('{$_POST['password']}')";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
 $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
 if($rows==1){
 $_SESSION['nombre'] = $nombre;
            // Redirección
 header("Location: u_principal.php");
 }else{
 echo 
 header("Location: o_denegado.php");

 }
    }
?>
   



    <div id="login">

        <form action="" method="post" id="bform">
            <fieldset id="bfieldset">
                <img src="img/logo_negro.png" alt="logo" id="blogo">
                <h1 id="bh1"> LOGIN</h1>


                <label for="nombre">
                    <input class="misel" type="text" name="nombre" required autofocus placeholder="USUARIO" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3,20}" id="nombre">

                </label>
                <br>
                <label for="password">

                    <input class="misel" type="Password" name="password" required placeholder="PASSWORD" id="password">
                </label>
                <br>
                <!--pattern="[A-Za-z]{4,20}"   IMPORTANTE PONERLO CUANDO DEJEMOS DE HACER PRUEBAS-->

                <button type="submit" id="envio">entrar</button>
                <br>
                
                <?php echo  date("Y");?>
               
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Una duda, cuando creas la variable $result, ¿a qué lo igualas usando el or?¿Sirve como un if? Es que es la primera vez que lo veo

Comment: Hola @unanobot, he puesto 'or die' en español 'o muere' , lo que quiero decir con éso es, que si no se ejecuta correctamente la consulta no siga. No te puedo decir mucho más ya que mis conococimientos  sobre el tema son, como ya he dicho antes son de 'novata', pero todo se andará...Un saludo!